# Data sends before requests finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request

I have to make an API request, which then I then take an ID out of the data I get back and put that into another API request. This was not my API design pattern but it is what it is.

My issue is, when it comes to sending a JSON response, the response is being sent before all of my requests are finished. Now I have tried with counters to check that all my requests have been made before sending the response but it does not work. I will show you where the issue is:

- So I make in total 26 API requests (crazy right).
- I have gone through debugging and seen that my counter correctly increments 26 times.

This is where I check the counter:

```
if ((counter === counterSum)) {
        res.send(projects);
}
```

The issue is, this code is running before all my counters can 'count'.

For example, at this point if I log the counter, it reaches to about 22 instead of 26. Often I see the counter log the same number 5 times or so because it has logged before my counter has had the chance to increment.

I have been going on this hours now so if anybody has an idea within the realm of Node.js, that would be amazing.

I will add some very simplified code showing all the request stages I have to go through and where I do the final log check:

```
let departmentProcesses = JSON.parse('[' + processes + ']');
Object.keys(departmentProcesses).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log('The process' + departmentProcesses[key]);
    let val = departmentProcesses[key];
    let id = val.id;
    let proccessURL = //url with + id
        // Get all instances by project id
        request({url: processURL},
            function (error, response, body) {
                //Convert the XML into JSON
                parseString(response.body, function (err, result) {
                    departmentData = JSON.stringify(result);
                });
                let instanceData = (JSON.parse(departmentData)).feed.entry;
                // Pushes to an array so I can sum up all the iterations
                counters.push(instanceData.length);
                Object.keys(instanceData).forEach(function (key) {
                    let val = instanceData[key];
                    let processId = val.id[0];
                    let nextURL = //url with + id";
                        request({url: nextURL},
                            function (error, response, body) {
                                //Convert the XML into JSON
                                parseString(response.body, function (err, result) {
                                    departmentData = JSON.stringify(result);
                                });
                                let instanceData = (JSON.parse(departmentData)).feed.entry;
                                let val = instanceData[0].id[0];
                                let todoLink = //url with + id";
                                    request({url: todoLink},
                                        function (error, response, body, callback) {
                                            //Convert the XML into JSON
                                            parseString(response.body, function (err, result) {
                                                departmentData = JSON.stringify(result);
                                            });
                                            let instanceEntry = (JSON.parse(departmentData)).feed.entry;
                                            if (typeof instanceEntry !== 'undefined' && instanceEntry) {
                                                let finalLink = //url with + id";
                                                    request({url: finalLink},
                                                        function (error, response, body) {
                                                            //Convert the XML into JSON
                                                            parseString(response.body, function (err, result) {
                                                                departmentData = JSON.stringify(result);
                                                            });
                                                            let instanceEntry = (JSON.parse(departmentData)).feed.entry;
                                                            if (typeof instanceEntry !== 'undefined' && instanceEntry) {
                                                                upNext = {
                                                                    // some data
                                                                };
                                                                let data = {
                                                                    // some data
                                                                }
                                                                processInstances.push(data);
                                                                counter++;
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                upNext = 'null';
                                                let data = {
                                                    // some data
                                                }
                                                counter++;
                                            }

                                            console.log(counter);
                                            let counterSum = counters.reduce(function (a, b) {
                                                return a + b;
                                            }, 0);

                                            if ((counter === counterSum)) {
                                                res.send(projects);
                                            }
                                        });
                            });
                });
            });
    let data = {
        processName: processName,
        id: id,
        instances: processInstances
    };
    projects.push(data);
});
```

Comment: Clearly a race condition as you describe, but we cannot help without seeing some code. How about adding a [Minmal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have added some code as simplified as i can @RandyCasburn

Comment: First question of many, many...  What do you expect: `proccessURL` to contain?

Comment: Yes, it is really difficult to show all of it but not lose the detail. The URL's you see are just basic API links like 'www.api.com/id'. They return a lot of XML which I then parse into JSON.

Comment: Essentially I need to send everything, only when the final request of the 'finalLink' is made

Comment: Not my question: In this statement: `let processURL = ` what do you think gets assigned to `processURL`? Also, the `parseString()` function uses a callback, implying that it is asynchronous by nature. Can you confirm that? In General, there are so many asynchronous calls going off simultaneously that you will not enjoy success with this code.

Comment: processURL is just a string. I took that code out to simplify it.  It is defined higher up in my code and gets appended to it the ID of that specific process.

Comment: The question I just asked is about an assignment statement that starts by declaring the variable - the variable is created within that statement (on line 6 of you sample) - it isn't created earlier - it is created right there. There is no appending of anything on that line - it is clear you need a much better understanding of this code before you ask any more questions about it.

Comment: Your best course of action, given the complexity of your use case, is to immediately discover, study, and implement Promises with Async/Await. That is done in node with https://github.com/request/request-promise-native

Comment: @RandyCasburn you don't need an extra library to use promises and async/await in node.js. The rest of your advice I agree with

Comment: @PatrickHund - sure, but not using the API the OP is using. For clarity, the OP is using this: https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback in his code - it creates callbacks. My recommendation was based upon that usage - did know if the OP was boxed in (or boxed themselves in) to that solution.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I will take a look. As I say, the process URL needs to have an ID added to the end of it which is done during the for loop. All of that works fine I have checked it all. It is purely a case of checking if everything is done before the response is sent.

Comment: @RandyCasburn ah, I see. I overlooked that